# one line ES6 change one item in Array

Tags: ecmascript-6, react-hooks

I have the code to change state with React

```
   const newArray = upfiles;
   newArray[i] = { ...upfiles[i], status: 'Ready' };
   setUpfiles([...newArray]);
```

I wonder if it can be done in one line.

Comment: Notice that `newArray` isn't actually a new array. The array literal `[... …]` creates the new array. Fix that first before trying to optimise number of lines.

Comment: Is `i` guaranteed to be an index into the array (i.e. `>= 0` and  `< upfiles.length`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setUpfile(Object.values({...upfiles, [i]:{...upfiles[i], status: "Ready"}}))
```

This should do the job in one line.

Also

```
setUpfile(upfiles.map((upfile, index) => index === i ? {...upfile, status:"Ready"} : upfile))
```

should work